# How to remove paddings in Bar chart? (Chart.JS)

Tags: javascript, bar-chart, chart.js

Is it possible to remove paddings inside bar chart?

```
<canvas id="weeksChartFallout" width="660" height="200"></canvas>

var falloutArray = [12, 24, 20, 15, 18, 20, 22, 10, 10, 12, 14, 10, 16, 16];

var dataWeeksFallouts = {
    labels: ["16.02", "17.02", "18.02", "19.02", "20.02", "21.02", "22.02", "23.02", "24.02", "25.02", "26.02", "27.02", "28.02", "01.03"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "Fallouts",
            fillColor: "rgba(63,107,245,0.67)",
            data: falloutArray
        }
    ]
};

var fc = document.getElementById('weeksChartFallout').getContext('2d');

window.weeksChartFallout = new Chart(fc).Bar(dataWeeksFallouts,{
    barShowStroke : false,
    barValueSpacing : 4, //distance between bars
    barValueWidth: 20,
    scaleShowLabels: false,
    scaleFontColor: "transparent",
    tooltipEvents: []
});
```

I mean space between first bar and left line and, especially space between last Bar and end of the chart ([screenshot](http://joxi.ru/ZrJXq3OsOzY82j)).

Here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JohnnyJuarez/2vueqcv7/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The x scale left and right paddings are calculated in the calculateXLabelRotation. If you have only these kind of charts you could simply replace this function to return no padding, like below

```
var originalCalculateXLabelRotation = Chart.Scale.prototype.calculateXLabelRotation
Chart.Scale.prototype.calculateXLabelRotation = function () {
    originalCalculateXLabelRotation.apply(this, arguments);
    this.xScalePaddingRight = 0;
    this.xScalePaddingLeft = 0;
}
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ov9p5qhz/

Note that there is still some spacing on the left and right - that comes from your `barValueSpacing: 4` option.

If you have other charts on the page that you don't want to keep separate, use `Chart.noConflict()`

Comment: man, you are genius!!! And one more time you rescue me ^)

And how I should use 'Chart.noConflict()' in right way? Should i put this in every chart except last one(the chart where I want to kill paddings)?

Comment: Just realized you don't actually need to use Chart.noConflict. You can actually do  `if (this.ctx.canvas.id == 'weeksChartFallout') {             this.xScalePaddingRight = 0; this.xScalePaddingLeft = 0; }` after `originalCalculateXLabelRotation.apply(this, arguments);`

Comment: You are The God of ChartJS :)

Comment: @potatopeelings thank you, thank you!  I have been trying to mix stacked bar and line charts with different x-axis rotation - perfect solution!